# Transistor Ic vs Vce Curve Trace for one 2N3906 Shows Weird Scope Display Not Sure Why

Tags: transistors, oscilloscope, pnp, function-generator, iv-curve

I recently built a transistor curve tracer on a breadboard with my Oscilloscope and Arbitrary Waveform Generator. Most BJT Si transistors (NPN and PNP) show typical/normal traces but one device under test - a 2N3906 - produces abnormal trace when collector-emitter voltage (Vce) goes higher than about 6 Volts. My other 2N3906 parts don't show this "abnormal" effect.

Does anyone know what is the cause of this abnormal trace (transistor or test setup for examples)?

I present a few images below showing my test setup, a good trace, and the weird trace.

### image 1: LTSpice showing my simple circuit

[image: image 1: LTSpice showing my simple circuit]

### image 2: breadboard showing the circuit I am using with scope probes and AWG waveform inputs

[image: image 2: breadboard showing the circuit I am using with scope probes and AWG waveform inputs]

### image 3: AWG setup

[image: image 3: AWG setup]

### image 4: a 2N3906 transistor showing typical results

[image: image 4: a 2N3906 transistor showing typical results]

### image 5: the problem result - a 2N3906 under test where Vce seems to break down after 6 volts DC

[image: image 5: the problem result - a 2N3906 under test where Vce seems to break down after 6 volts DC]

### Link to my report on this subject

[http://www.biophysicslab.com/2021/04/27/testing_transistor_hfe](http://www.biophysicslab.com/2021/04/27/testing_transistor_hfe/#measure-hfe-using-an-oscilloscope-and-arbitrary-waveform-generator-awg)

Comment: I couldn't *quickly* read all those details. But since it is very common for BJTs to have reverse-voltage breakdown of their BE junctions at around 6 volts or so, is it possible you've got a pin-identification problem with your device?

Comment: Looks like the CE junction got zapped and acts as a SCR with a negative incremental resistance . Might be good for a tunnel diode oscillator at RF if biased at -7V. ;) This is a breakdown arc failure with say 40K/mm might be 40V/um so 7V is about a 175 nm gap that the E-Field bridged This PNP should be good to -40V and act like a Zener near -50V.  In the 70’s I needed a HV Zener for uA ref. So I choose a transistor breakdown voltage to make the old TV work.

Comment: 6 V breakdown is indeed to low for Base-Collector but the expected value for Base-Emitter. Note that BJTs do work "upside down" (so swapping collector and emitter) so that's why you still get the transistor curves but the you will see breakdown at a much lower voltage and also a **lower beta**.

Comment: Are we assuming this PNP is actually an NPN  with a negative trace?

Comment: Looking at your photo it does look like you have connectied things up properly. Do realize that the 2N3906 is a PNP so the collector voltage needs to be negative with respect to ground. So in your LTSpice schematic, both V_stair and V_triangle would need to have a **negative value**.

Comment: Is everyone agreed , it’s a defective part?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie:  "So in your LTSpice schematic, both V_stair and V_triangle would need to have a negative value. "  Sort of, maybe.  Only the difference matters.  [This IV tracer](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/iv-1-toc) does PNP transistors with just the normal 5V power supply of an Arduino Nano.

Comment: @JRE Sure, a negative supply isn't needed **if you connect the emitter of a PNP to the + 5 V**. But if you connect that emitter to ground (0 V), which is what is done here, then you would need - 5 V.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie:  Yep.

Comment: The AWG image shows both waveforms going from -.7 to -5 for staircase, and 0 to -5 triangle volts respectively. I think I meet the negative supply issues on physical board. LTSpice simulation also uses negative voltage waveforms as well although the signal images are a little hard to see.